# Populate data from DataGridView into a TextBox in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

So I am trying to load data from a `datagridview` into a `textbox` by clicking on a row from the `datagridview`.

I have this at the moment:

```
    private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
            this.Hide();
            frmPrincipal frm = new frmPrincipal();

            frm.txtCarga.Text = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            frm.txtCarga.Focus();
            frm.txtCarga.SelectAll();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro\nDetalhes: " + ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

But because I don't have the `frm.Show()` it does not show. Basically I press F1 and another form with a `datagridview` shows and there I will click into the row to put the values into the `textbox`. But it does not work.

What should I do?

Comment: it is not clear what you want to do... you want to show on the same form or other?

Comment: It looks like the values probably *are* in the textbox, but as you mentioned, you will never see them because you never call `frm.Show()`.  If you set your keys on the dresser and never turn the bedroom light on, you may not be able to see them, but it doesn't mean that they aren't sitting there on the dresser waiting for someone to turn the light on...

Answer (score 0):

Your are going to change your dataGridFrom to include a public property which you set and can be called from your original calling form after closing.

```
public string dataValue = "";

private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
        dataValue = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        this.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Erro\nDetalhes: " + ex.Message, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

In your original form you have somewhere something like

```
dataGridFrom.Show();
```

Your going to want to change that to

```
dataGridFrom.ShowDialog();
```

This will pause your other form while it waits for this dataGridform to close.  Right after that your going to want to add (showing previous line to help)

```
dataGridForm.ShowDialog();
this.txtCarga.Text = dataGridFrom.dataValue;
```

That will close the form and update your textbox to what you want.  You can also do Show() but you will need to create an event I think and this is a lot easier.

Comment: No. It will open a new form. I do not want it

Comment: can you explain where the textbox is so I can modify the anser.

Comment: you are currently setting the textbox on the frmPrincipal with a new object.  do you have a differnt frmPrincipal that you called this form with?

Comment: The text box is in the frmPrincipal. After double clicking on a row it would go to frmPrincipal, because it's already opened.

Comment: @Miggs I think this is what your getting at.